Problem to insert with multiple-cursors.el
I’m trying multiple-cursors in emacs.
I open emacs wiht emacs -Q. Install "multiple-cursors" with package-list-packages. After that I opened a file "test.org" with C-x C-f, and I wrote some text like:
#+begin_export latex
int main () {
  printf("Please help!");
  printf("help me with multiple-cursors");
  printf("problem, need help");
}
#+end_export

I selected the first word "help" using Ctrl-space Ctrl-f, then selected all occurrences with M-x mc/mark-all-like-this, which worked correctly.
After pressing Ctrl-g and Backspace, all occurrences of "help" were deleted. This is fine.
However, when I typed some text "Help", it was only written at the first cursor, not at the other two. Could this be due to the header?

Please provide a step-by-step recipe to repro the problem, starting from emacs -Q (but loading multiple-cursors.el). At each step, say what you see and what you expected to see.

Hi Drew, I topened emacs with the command emacs -Q, then installed the package multiple-cursors from the menu, in the scratch tried to use it as explained with some text, and it worked fine. I tried after in my version, with try and it worked well again. Don't know what's changed, but emacs -Q command, and the methodology to explain the problem was good. Thank you.

No sorry, it started again. I opened a file "test.org" with C-x C-f, then between the headers #+begin_export latex and #+end_export, I wrote some text like list nested\nprintf("nested")\nprintf("nested"). I selected the first word "nested" using Ctrl-space Ctrl-f, then selected all occurrences with M-x mc/mark-all-like-this, which worked correctly. After pressing Ctrl-g and Backspace, all occurrences of "nested" were deleted. However, when I typed some text "kbf", it was only written at the first cursor, not at the other two. Could this be due to the header?

Put all relevant info in the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time and are not searchable.

Thanks. I have modified the question, accordingly.
